# AIR Mobile: External classes not loading

Tags: actionscript-3, air, flashdevelop

I'm having trouble targeting a normal as3 swf to air mobile so i made a simple test app to check and try to understand which is the problem.
I'm using flashdevelop 4 and latest AIR sdk.

I exported an SWC with a simple MC exported with class name *BlackBox*
Here's my Main code (package and imports ommited but I even imported the BlackBox class) :

```
public class Main extends Sprite 
{
    public var cajaNegra:MovieClip

    public function Main():void 
    {
        stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
        stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;
        stage.addEventListener(Event.DEACTIVATE, deactivate);

        // touch or gesture?
        Multitouch.inputMode = MultitouchInputMode.TOUCH_POINT;

        // entry point
        cajaNegra = new BlackBox();
        addChild(cajaNegra)
        cajaNegra.x = stage.stageWidth/2
        cajaNegra.y = stage.stageHeight / 2
        }
}
```

everything works as it should, but when I create a custom *BlackBox.as* in the src folder the app doesn't show anything. I added a text field named *miTexto*.

BlackBox.as

```
public class BlackBox extends MovieClip 
{
    public var miTexto:TextField

    public function BlackBox() 
    {
        super();
        if (stage) init();
        else addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);


    }

    private function init(e:Event = null):void 
    {
        removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
        // entry point
        miTexto.text = "changed text"
    }

}
```

In this case the debugger throws in the line *miTexto.text = "changed text"*:

```
 [Fault] exception, information=TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

did you forget to do: addChild(miTextTo); ?

Comment: Okay, I also noticed you haven't done a miTexto = new TextField();

Comment: tried it. do I have to do a new TextField() if i placed it in flash? wouldn't it replace it with a default one?

Comment: Anyway, I think the problem resides in using an external .as file for the class because I commented all the textfield related code and still shows a blank screen. The only way to make it work again is deleting BlackBox.as